# WooCommerce: Adding users to groups based on single use coupon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site that sells consumer goods. We have a referral program where doctors around the US get compensation based profits created by those who use the doctors referral/discount code.

This is all fine, however the code is a 1 per customer use as we only want the customers first order to receive the discount.

This is where the problem lies, the doctors still need to be compensated for all the profit brought in from people who used their code on their first purchase.

My idea is to use [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/)([docs](http://docs.itthinx.com/document/groups/)). Then monthly use the group filter in orders to pull down orders for each doctor.

So what I am trying to do is create a little script that adds a customer to a [group](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) based on the coupon code they use.  I am manually creating group and coupon code at the same time  (they will alway be the same). I also just grabbed the group_id from the groups plugin section. wondering if we can also pull group id from name.

Here is what I currently have that is not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_group', 10, 1);
function coupon_group( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $coupon_codes = $order->get_coupon_codes();
    $coupon_name = 'dr_x';
    $group_id = 2;

    foreach($coupon_codes as $coupon_code ){
        if ($coupon_code->get_name() == $coupon_name) {
            $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); 

            if ($user_id) { 
                $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name($coupon_name);
                $is_a_member = Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id , $group_id ->group_id );

                if (!$is_a_member) {
                   Groups_User_Group::create( array( 'user_id' => $user_id, 'group_id' => $group ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up going the route of roles over Groups as i couldnt get that to update properly.

I used User Role Editor to create new roles.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'coupon_group', 10, 1);

function coupon_group( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $coupon_codes = $order->get_coupon_codes();
    $coupon_name = 'CouponCode'; //manually created coupon code

    foreach($coupon_codes as $coupon_code ){
        $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); 

        if ($coupon_code == $coupon_name) {
            if ($user_id) {
                $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
                $user->remove_role('customer'); 
                $user->add_role($coupon_name);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```